# Problems when trying to run FParsec in F# Interactive

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, f#, f#-interactive, fparsec

I'm trying to run some [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/) code in F# Interactive but with no success. I am
 able to build and run this `tutorial.fs` file, but the same isn't happening with FSI, as it didn't recognize `FParsec.dll`.

I've already tried running the `#r "Parsec"` command in FSI but it was of no avail.

Anyone has a clue on what might be the problem here?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

FParsec is not GAC installed, therefore you need to put the full path to the dll in the #r directive, not just the name of the assembly. Also, don't forget that "...FParsec is built as two DLLs. The C# bits are compiled into the FParsecCS.dll and the F# bits (which depend on the C# bits) are compiled into FParsec.dll." ([section 3.2](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/download-and-installation.html) of the documentation). e.g.

```
#r @"C:\FParsecCS.dll"
#r @"C:\FParsec.dll"
```

Comment: I was *sure* I had tried it with the full path, too. Seems I was mistaken.

Comment: If you are always using the dll you can add it to FSI automatically via the command line with `-r "C:\Fparsec.dll"`.  The option is hiding in the FSI options in visual studio

Comment: Also, be sure you reference FParsecCS before FParsec, otherwise you'll get an error FS0074.

Comment: Reset the Interactive after every script change.

Comment: In visual studio, to reset the interactive F# window, right-click anywhere in the F# interactive window -> "Reset Interactive Session"